# Update TableView cell data

Tags: ios, swift, struct, tableview, viewdidload

I'm new to Swift/Xcode and reached a problem with updating TableView cell data. I can't quite seem to find/implement the answer to this simple thing from any similar StackOverflow questions either.

I have an app that starts making an api call every 1 sec on a timer once a button is pressed but the problem is that when all tableview data gets loaded from an array with `viewDidLoad()` theres obviously no data to display in the label as no call has been made yet.

Once I press the button the data starts flowing but nothing appears in the label. I believe this is because the label needs to be updated upon every call in order to display the new data.

The data is also an NSAttributedString from HTML. Not sure if this is relevant though as it seems to work fine in test cell’s outside of the tableview.

Essentially what I want to do is somehow call

```
    cell.cellLabelTwo.attributedText = tableData[indexPath.row].secondRowLabel
```

from the code shown below every time a new api call is made and update cellLabelTwo with the new % gain data.

```
struct MyData {
    var imageRow: UIImage
    var firstRowLabel: String
    var secondRowLabel: NSAttributedString
}

var tableData: [MyData] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableData = [
        MyData(imageRow: UIImage(named: "ada.png")!, firstRowLabel: "ADA/USDT", secondRowLabel: adaPercentGainString.htmlToAttributedString!)
    ]

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tableData.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "protoCellOne") as! TableViewCell

    cell.cellImageOne.image = tableData[indexPath.row].imageRow
    cell.cellLabelOne.text = tableData[indexPath.row].firstRowLabel
    cell.cellLabelTwo.attributedText = tableData[indexPath.row].secondRowLabel
    cell.cellLabelTwo.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 19)
    cell.cellLabelTwo.textAlignment = .right

    return cell

}
```

Edit: I have added `@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!` and connected it to View Controller, I've also assigned the tableview to datasource and delegate of View Controller. Adding the IB outlet seemed to be solution to this for many other people but it still not showing anything in the cell label...

Comment: You need to check your {} carefully, you may simply have a function inside another.  Your `reloadData` is in the wrong place, because you need to reload after the data has been retrieved, which is inside the completion handler closure. Also you will need to dispatch the reload into the main queue.

Answer (score -1):

You simply need to reload the table view after each API call.

`tableView.reloadData()`

This would be best called in a completion handler of your API call, but you don’t provide your code where the API is called.

Reloading the data will call the delegate method `cellForRowAt:` for each cell, which is where you have the code that you want to run.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Yes, I've played around with `tableView.reloadData()` a fair bit already. I've tried it as a completion handler in my api call (which is actually just an HTML scrape) but get the error **Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)'** https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAUHa.png

Comment: @JasonN Can you share the code for numberOfRowsInSection? That could be where the problem is.

Comment: Its already referenced in the code on the original question (or at least the only reference of it appearing in my code). I think the problem here might be that the are two different `tableView()` functions with different parameters and `tableView.reloadData()` doesn't know which one to reload. For example, heres what I get when I click on the red error warning (the grey warnings that then appear): https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZbMs.png

Comment: its an NSAttributedString I'm trying to show in the cell label by the way (due  to html conversion). Not sure if this is relevant but thought I'd mention...